# No Calling Format in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I'm upgrading software from boto to boto3 and had a question about the `boto connection.calling_format`
Is it not required in boto3 connections anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no `calling_format` option for boto3.client. See [This](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client). I have never used that option or seen before in boto3. You don't need.

Answer (score 1):

The `calling_format` really only applied to S3 where it defaults to subdomain buckets.

Subdomains can be a bit of a pain to proxy or require more firewall rules, which is why the option to use a path based calling format for S3 still exists. To do so

```
config = Config(
    s3={'addressing_style': 'path'},
)

s3_client = boto3.client(
    's3', config=config,
)
```

Comment: allowed values for addressing_style ['virtual' (default, or when None), 'auto', 'path', None] from botocore.config.Config._validate_s3_configuration